# Read file contents without a picker in a windows store app

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to read the contents of a file on the root of my c:\ drive in a windows store app.

I **can** do this using a FilePicker but I what to do it without the user having to do anything. So is there any way in following code that I can ditch the file picker and have this happen automatically?

```
        FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;

        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

        StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

When the picker is shown I browse to the root of the c drive here.

```
        if (file!=null)
        {
             ...I then read the file and this works fine.
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

No. A drive root folder is not a safe location for any app to access, so user's consent is necessary and is done through the file picker. You can use the future access list to access the selected folder once user allows your app to access it.

Typically apps can work well just accessing the blessed document folders and their own app data folder. If you really need access to any location without any user's input you should consider creating a Win32/WPF application or a service.

Answer (score 0):

Place your whole code in

`protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)`

`{`

`Place your code`

`}`

Comment: No, you mis-understand the question. I don't want the picker to appear. I want code to do the file selection without using a picker